# Rename tag http-accept-langauge to http-accept-language

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request

Could someone with sufficient permissions please correct the following typo in a tag?

Current: [http-accept-langauge](/questions/tagged/http-accept-langauge)
Corrected: [http-accept-language](/questions/tagged/http-accept-language)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took liberty of retagging questions. Orphaned typo tag should disappear at midnight by itself. If this typo continues to propagate, it could be good idea to make it a synonym.

Comment: You missed a few; I took care of three stragglers.

Comment: Thank you, @Charles and Oleg!